# Protocol associatedtype as a type for delegate

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, delegates, protocols

The purpose of what I am trying to do is to make it possible to put objects which implements *`ChildOfRootClass`* to one array (look at AbstractClass -> children) and put at each *`ChildNClass`* instance object a link to its parent (look *`weak var delegate`* variable). So I want make type of *`delegate`* in each *`ChildOfRootClass`* generic.

Hope code will explain what exactly I have meant.

```
    // Parent class for RootClass and Child1Class, Child2Class etc
    class AbstractClass {
        init() { }
        init(smth: String) { }

        var children = [String : ChildOfRootClass]()

        func add(key: String, child: ChildOfRootClass) {
            children[key] = child
        }
    }
```

Delegate protocols for each of children.

```
    protocol ChildDelegate: class { }
    protocol Child1ClassDelegate: ChildDelegate { func rr() }
    protocol Child2ClassDelegate: ChildDelegate { }

    class RootClass: AbstractClass {
        override init() {
            super.init()
        }
    }

    extension RootClass: Child1ClassDelegate {
        func rr() { }
    }
```

Children classes.

```
    protocol ChildOfRootClass {
        associatedtype ChildOfRootClassDelegateType: ChildDelegate

        weak var delegate: ChildOfRootClassDelegateType? { set get }
        init(smth: String)
    }

    class Child1Class: AbstractClass, ChildOfRootClass {
        typealias ChildOfRootClassDelegateType = Child1Delegate

        weak var delegate: Child1Delegate?

        required override init(smth: String) {
            super.init(smth: smth)
        }
    }

    extension Child1Class: Child2ClassDelegate { }

    class Child2Class: AbstractClass/*, ChildOfRootClass*/ {
        required override init(smth: String) {
            super.init(smth: smth)
        }
    }
```

How I want to use it.

```
    let root   = RootClass()
    let child1 = Child1Class(smth: "1")
    let child2 = Child2Class(smth: "2")

    child1.add(key: "child2", child: child2)
    root.add(key: "child1", child: child1)
```

Comment: If you could do this, what would you do with `children[key].delegate`? it only conforms to `ChildDelegate`. Does `ChildDelegate` have methods you could actually call on it? (It is almost never a good idea to mix class inheritance with protocol associated types. It will bite you again and again. You shouldn't use PATs at all unless you have very strong need for them; they're a very advanced tool with many sharp edges. The answer is going to be: "do it another way;" so it's important to nail down what you're really trying to do with all this.)

Comment: Any time you encounter problems like this, you should start from the end-usage rather than the construction and work backwards from there. So now that you've built a small tree, what would you do with it and its delegates?

Comment: There is  `extension RootClass: Child1ClassDelegate` which have a method, and if set `children[key].delegate = self` it will be possible to call this method from Child1Class

Comment: It is more theoretical case, just wondering is it possible to resolve such case using this instruments.

Comment: Theoretical cases of making something generic for its own sake tend to fail really fast in Swift. When you run up against a problem in a real code base, the generic problem often falls away and there is a reasonably straightforward solution in Swift.

Comment: Your line `children[key].delegate = self` is impossible, however. What is the (statically defined, known at compile time) type of `children[key].delegate`? The best you can know is that it's `ChildDelegate`. That's not enough information to know that `self` conforms to the right protocol. You have a basic type problem here, rather than a Swift implementation problem.